# android delaying flashlight

Tags: android, flashlight

I made a simple application with 2 buttons to test flashlights.

```
button1.setOnClickListener...etc
    if (cameraObj ==null){ return; }
    Camera.Parameters cameraParams =cameraObj.getParameters();
    if(cameraParams.getFlashMode() == null) { return;}
    cameraParams.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    cameraObj.setParameters(cameraParams);
    cameraObj.startPreview(); 

button2.setOnClick etc...
    if(cameraObj==null){ return; }
    Camera.Parameters cameraParams = cameraObj.getParameters();
    cameraParams.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    cameraObj.setParameters(cameraParams);
    cameraObj.stopPreview();
```

The application was tested on 2 devices: HTC ONE and HTC DESIRE 500

The application works good on both. The problem is: there's a delay on turning on/off the flashlight.

When I press on and off very fast, the flashlight on DESIRE 500 its turning off and on as I press the buttons, but on HTC ONE there is a delay (it looks like you are not allowed to switch that fast the flashlights). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by adding a fixed delay using `Hander` which will trigger the flash after a delay,

```
// variable to fix the timeout duration in milliseconds
// 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
double TIME_OUT = 2*1000;

       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // time has been reached, turn the flash on
               if (cameraObj ==null){ return; }
               Camera.Parameters cameraParams =cameraObj.getParameters();
               if(cameraParams.getFlashMode() == null) { return;}
               cameraParams.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
               cameraObj.setParameters(cameraParams);
               cameraObj.startPreview(); 
                }
            }
        }, TIME_OUT);
```

Comment: I tested the app on HTC ONE more carefully and seems like the solution is: ON HTC ONE I have to press 2 times the "off" button, in order flashlight to turn off. That's creepy.   So on Desire if I press just one time, the flash will go off, and on ONE I have to press twice. (is the same app) it could be because I use a deprecated class? (One got Android 5.x and Desire Android 4.1x)

Comment: It could be a device specific issue too. Some devices need some time to initialize the camera features where some other runs it immediately. So far no issues with you code!

Comment: If i press one time On and two times OFF very fast it works like I press on Desire one time ON and one time OFF very fast.